# jQuery modal dialog first open works, subsequent opens fail

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, dialog, modal-dialog

I've got an MVC project written in C# using Razor Engine. I'm calling a modal through jQuery which loads a form to POST fields to my controller via AJAX, returning updated content that loads into the calling DIV.

This works wonderfully ... once. Attempting to open the modal again (to edit a different row), the form loads into the browser as if redirected, rather than displaying it in a modal dialog.

In my view, I'm calling my modal from a link (Custom HTML Helper, line breaks added only for readability):

```
@Html.NoEncodeActionLink("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>", "Edit Phone", "Edit", "PhoneLinks", 
                         theseRouteValues: new { id = item.id }, 
                         theseHtmlAttributes: new { 
                             data_modal = "", 
                             data_toggle = "modal", 
                             data_dismiss = "modal", 
                             data_title = "Edit Phone", 
                             data_btnlabel = "Edit Phone", 
                             data_callingdiv = "replaceTargetPhone", 
                             data_whichform = "PhoneLinkModalForm", 
                             @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" 
                         }
                        )
```

Clicks on the link are caught in my jQuery and handled there with AJAX.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    // Initialize the modal DIV
    var $modalDiv = jQuery("<div class='modalContent'></div>")
    .appendTo('body')
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        position: { my: 'center', at: 'center', collision: 'fit' },
        show: { effect: 'blind', duration: 300 },
        hide: { effect: 'explode', duration: 500 },
        close: function () { jQuery('div.modalContent').empty(); }
    });

    // Create a modal popup when a modal-generating link is clicked
    jQuery("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Gather parameters from the link into variables for readability
        var sourceLink = jQuery(this); 
        var sourceHref = sourceLink.attr('href'); // Relative path to controller method
        var titleData = sourceLink.data('title'); // Title for the modal dialog
        var callingDiv = "#" + sourceLink.data('callingdiv'); // #replaceTarget divs ... where to apply refresh after AJAX returns
        var whichForm = "#" + sourceLink.data('whichform'); // ID of the form called by the link that will be submitted in the modal
        var btnProceed = sourceLink.data('btnlabel'); // Which function was called: Create/Edit/Delete (for button labelling)
        var btnCancel = "Cancel";       
        var theseButtons = {};

        // Submit Button
        theseButtons[btnProceed] = function () {
            // Send parameters to another function for processing
            // On success, the processForm() function closes the modal
            processForm(theModalContent, callingDiv, theModalContainer, sourceHref, whichForm, titleData);
        };

        // Cancel Button
        theseButtons[btnCancel] = function () {
            jQuery('div.modalContent').empty().dialog('close');
            return false;
        };

        // Add a few parameters to the modal (title, buttons, etc.) and load content
        $modalDiv.empty();
        $modalDiv
            .load(sourceHref)
            .dialog({
                title: titleData,
                buttons: theseButtons
            });

        $modalDiv.dialog('open');
    });

});
```

The processForm() function handles the AJAX call to the controller, and it works as expected. On success, it closes the modal with the same line of code in the Cancel button:

```
jQuery('div.modalContent').empty().dialog('close');
```

I can open the modal the first time without issue.
[First call to modal works perfectly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1l66.jpg)

I can cancel the modal and reopen it as many times as I want.

If I submit the form in the modal, the form is processed correctly, my database updates correctly, and the content reloads in the target DIV correctly. However, if I then try to open a subsequent modal (for editing another phone number), the form doesn't load into a modal. It instead loads as the body of a new HTML document.
[Second call to modal fails.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52QNO.jpg)

I have tried closing the modal in many different ways:

```
.dialog('destroy')
```

or

```
.remove()
```

or

```
.dialog('destroy').remove()
```

I have also tried initializing the modal within the "a[data-modal].on('click') function, rather than initializing on document ready.

All working variations work the first time, then fail after the first submit.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: Added processForm() function code.

```
function processForm(thisModalContent, thisCallingDiv, thisModalContainer, thisMethod, thisForm, thisTitle) {

    // Capture the form fields
    var formPost = jQuery(thisForm);

    // Serialize the fields to an array
    // This step is necessary to handle phone number mask removal
    var values = formPost.serializeArray();

    // Some code here removes phone masking and 
    // puts the raw numbers back into the array

    // Convert the serialized array to a single string for POST
    var serializedPost = jQuery.param(values);

    // Send data to controller and handle response
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: thisMethod,
        type: 'POST',
        data: serializedPost,
        error: function (x, e) {
            if (x.status === 0) {
                alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            } else if (x.status === 404) {
                alert('Requested URL not found.');
            } else if (x.status === 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error.\n DataSent: \n' + serializedPost + '\n Response Text: \n' + x.responseText);
            } else if (e === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.\n' + x.responseJSON);
            } else if (e === 'timeout') {
                alert('Request Time out.');
            } else {
                alert('Unknown Error.\n' + x.responseText);
            }
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                //jQuery('div.modalContent').dialog('destroy').remove();  // Didn't Work
                //jQuery('div.modalContent').dialog('destroy');  // Didn't Work
                //jQuery('div.modalContent').remove();  // Didn't Work
                jQuery('div.modalContent').empty().dialog('close');
                jQuery(thisCallingDiv).load(result.url);
            } else {
                thisModalContent.html(result);
            }
        }
    });
return false;
}
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that while the code in this example is referencing phone numbers, I have a DIV for addresses on the same page. The Address editing link click calls the same jQuery modal.

If I submit a phone edit, subsequent calls to the modal from phone edit links are broken.

BUT I can successfully call the address edit modal ... once. Then subsequent calls to it are broken.

Refreshing the page fixes the modal from both link types (phones and addresses). Both types can be opened and cancelled repeatedly until one is submitted. Then that one is broken, but the other still works until it is submitted.

Comment: So the problem only happens if you try to open the modal after calling `processForm()`? I suspect something in there is breaking it.

Comment: Added processForm() function code and some additional related findings.